# Dos <select> enlazados (Pais y Provincia) que no se enlazan

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo dos select, uno cargo los países, en el otro las provincias que "reacciona" de acuerdo al país que se seleccionó primero. Recién consulté cómo traer desde una BD el código de un país y hacer que ese select de países me muestre el país que viene desde la BD, pero tambien tengo una provincia que traigo desde la BD. Ahora bien, aplicando esa carga, "no reacciona" el select de provincias ya que no se carga de acuerdo al select seleccionado mediante el dato de la BD. El select de países se carga con:

```
<select id="pais" class="ui fluid search dropdown" name="pais">
        <option value="0"></option>
        <?php
            $conexion = new Conexion();
            $stmt = $conexion -> prepare("SELECT paiscod, paisnom FROM paises ORDER BY paisnom");
            $stmt->execute();

            while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            if ( $row['paiscod'] == $pais ) { ?>
                <option value = "<?php echo $row['paiscod']?>" selected><?php echo ($row['paisnom'])?></option>
            <?php } else { ?>
                <option value = "<?php echo $row['paiscod']?>"><?php echo ($row['paisnom'])?></option>
            <?php }
            } 
        ?>
    </select>


    <select id="provincias" class="ui fluid search dropdown" name="selectProvincias">
        <option value=""></option>
    </select>



    $id_pais = $_POST['id_pais'];

    $conexion = new Conexion();
    $stmt = $conexion -> prepare("SELECT provincod, provinnom FROM provincia WHERE paiscod = :valor");
    $stmt->bindParam(':valor', $id_pais);
    $stmt->execute();

    if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {   
            $html .= '<option value = "'.$row['provincod'].'">'. $row['provinnom'].'</option>';
        }
    }
    echo $html;


    <script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#pais").change(function() {
            $("#pais option:selected").each(function() {
                id_pais = $(this).val();
                $.post("provincias.php", {
                    id_pais: id_pais
                }, function(data) {
                    $("#provincias").html(data);
                });
            });
        })
    });
    </script>
```

PREGUNTA 1: ¿Por qué el js no reconoce el cambio en el select país cuando toma el valor desde la BD ?

PREGUNTA 2: ¿Cómo le paso el código de la provincia que viene por BD para que me muestre la provincia seleccionada ?

Comment: A ver si entendi, cuando eliges un pais el select no ejecuta el metodo `change`?

Comment: ¿Para qué el `each` del `option:selected` si sólo se puede seleccionar una opción? Mejor mete directo `id_pais = $("#pais option:selected").val()` Y es mejor que tu código de php que consulta la BD por las provincias lo pongas en otra clase, y en `$.ajax` pones la ruta al archivo.

Comment: @linux Tambien puede eliminar esta línea `$("#pais option:selected").each(function() {` que esta demás y ya esta.

Comment: Puede ser un problema en el archivo `provincias.php` ¿Qué te muestra en la consola si haces `console.log(data)`?

Comment: cuando traigo el codigo del pais de la base de datos, no me filtra el select de las provincias...

Comment: 1) una pregunta por pregunta. 2)haz las preguntas "técnicas" y concisas. No existen los "select enlazados". Si al lanzarse un evento no se ejecuta nada, es una cuestión. Si tu js falla al ejecutarse, otra. Si falla el php, otra. Si falla el procesamiento de la respuesta, otra. Con un par de logs puedes hacer la pregunta correcta.

Comment: @MatiasOlivera deduciendo del código por como lo puso, provincias.php es el mismo archivo, lo cual sería la razón por la cual no sirve, pero si realmente es otro archivo entonces hay mucho que revisar antes de dar una respuesta definitiva (Network de Developers Tool, console.log(data), debuggear el archivo php, etc...

Comment: el codigo funciona. Cuando se carga el formulario, se cargan los países... cuando selecciono un país, me flitra las provincias, el problema radica en cuando traigo por base de datos, el código del país, el select de las provincias no se carga para ese país y menos el código de la provincia almacenado en la base de datos...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me permitiré comentar algunas cosas sobre tu código, por partes.

Quería decírtelo en comentario, pero el espacio no me daría.

No lo dices en tu pregunta, pero supongo que este código se encuentra en un archivo diferente de `provincias.php`

Digamos que el archivo se llama `paises.php`.

### Código en `paises.php`:

**1. No preparares algo ya preparado**

Las consultas preparadas se usan cuando intervienen datos desde otra parte. No es el caso aquí. La consulta *está ya preparada*, no hay riesgo de mandarla directamente mediante el método `query`:

```
$stmt = $conexion -> prepare("SELECT paiscod, paisnom FROM paises ORDER BY paisnom");
$stmt->execute();
```

Por lo tanto, esto sería suficiente:

```
$stmt =$conexion->query("SELECT paiscod, paisnom FROM paises ORDER BY paisnom");
```

**2. Todo el procedimiento del `while` que tienes, se puede simplificar así:**

```
//Crear un array con los datos
//PDO::FETCH_ASSOC  se usa con fetchAll, no con fetch
$arrDatos = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

//Verificar si hubo datos. El uso de rowCount para esto es sólo un mito 
//en PDO basta con verificar la respuesta del fetchAll

if ($arrDatos)
{
    //Implementamos una forma más limpia de hacer las cosas
    //Una variable que recoja todo y vaya concatenado

    $strHtml='';
    foreach ($arrDatos as $row)
    {
        if ( $row['paiscod'] == $pais ) 
        { 
            $strHtml.='<option value = "'.$row["paiscod"].' selected>'.$row["paisnom"].'</option>';
        } else {
            $strHtml.='<option value = "'.$row["paiscod"].'>'.$row["paisnom"].'</option>';
        }
     }
     //Fuera del bucle imprimimos la variable concatenada
     echo $strHtml;

 }else{
       echo "No se encontraron países";
 }
```

**3. El script debe estar en `paises.php`:**

Lo puedes mejorar, como se ha dicho en comentarios. Imagino que en el HTML tienes un select cuyo id es `provincias`.

El script, aunque quizá funcione, está usando código obsoleto: `$(document).ready(function() {...` es obsoleto a partir de jQuery3. Se recomienda usar `$(function() {...`.

Del mismo modo, las peticiones Ajax se recomienda que tengan al menos la posibilidad de manejar `done` en caso de éxito, y `fail` en caso de error ([ver aquí](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)).

```
  <script language="javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#pais").change(function() {
            $("#pais option:selected").each(function() {
                id_pais = $(this).val();
                $.post("provincias.php", {
                    id_pais: id_pais
                }, function(data) {
                    $("#provincias").html(data);
                });
            });
        })
    });
    </script>
```

---

La petición que se hace a través de Ajax/jQuery debe ir dirigida a otro archivo diferente. En este caso es el archivo indicado en la url de la petición `provincias.php`.

### Código en `provincias.php`:

```
$id_pais = $_POST['id_pais'];

$conexion = new Conexion();
$stmt = $conexion -> prepare("SELECT provincod, provinnom FROM provincia WHERE paiscod = :valor");
$stmt->bindParam(':valor', $id_pais);
$stmt->execute();

//Es un error común usar fetch combinado con `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`
//Así no se obtiene nada, debes usar fetchAll
//por eso no obtenías las provincias

//Como en países, almacenamos los datos en un arrego
$arrDatos=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))

//Desechamos el mito del rowCount, verificando los datos directamente
//como hicimos en países

if ($arrDatos)
{
    $strHtml="";
    foreach ($arrDatos as $row)
    {

        $strHtml .= '<option value = "'.$row['provincod'].'">'. $row['provinnom'].'</option>';
    }

    echo $strHtml;

}else{

    echo "No se encontraron provincias";

}
```